# Is it possible to set dtype to an existing structured array, or add "column name" to an existing array?

Tags: python, numpy

this code (snippet_1) is to construct a [structured array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/user/basics.rec.html)

```
>>> dt = np.dtype([('name', np.str_, 16), ('age', np.int)])
>>> x = np.array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)], dtype=dt)
>>> x
array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)],
      dtype=[('name', '<U16'), ('age', '<i8')])
```

this code is to set dtype to a given simple array

```
arr = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50]) 
arr = arr.astype('float64')
```

this code (snippet_3) is trying to set dtype to a structured array,

```
x = np.array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)])
x = x.astype(dt)
```

of course, set dtype this way causes ValueError

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-201b69204e82> in <module>()
      1 x = np.array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)])
----> 2 x = x.astype(dt)

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Sarah'
```

Is it possible to set dtype to an existing structured array? something like snippet_3?

Why would I want to do this? Because there is a handy approach to access data in the setting of snippet_1.

```
x['name']
```

If I can add "column name" to an existing array, that would be cool.

Comment: Why do you want to set the dtype of existing structured array? The dtype is an attribute of the array. You can GET it, but I don't think you can change it, especially if it already has data in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html#numpy.lib.recfunctions.unstructured_to_structured)

```
x = np.array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)])
x
# array([['Sarah', '16'],
#        ['John', '17']], dtype='<U5')
dt = np.dtype([('name', np.str_, 16), ('age', np.int)])

import numpy.lib.recfunctions as nlr

xs = nlr.unstructured_to_structured(x, dtype=dt)
xs
# array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)],
#       dtype=[('name', '<U16'), ('age', '<i8')])
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the following input:

```
dt = np.dtype([('name', np.str_, 16), ('age', np.int)])
x = np.array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)], dtype=dt)

# array([('Sarah', 16), ('John', 17)],
#      dtype=[('name', '<U16'), ('age', '<i8')])
```

Let's **add a column** to the structured array, like this:

```
new_dt = np.dtype(x.dtype.descr + [('weight', float)])
xx = np.zeros(x.shape, dtype=new_dt)

xx['name'] = x['name']
xx['age'] = x['age']

xx['weight'] = [86.7, 78.9]
```

and gives:

```
# array([('Sarah', 16, 86.7), ('John', 17, 78.9)],
#      dtype=[('name', '<U16'), ('age', '<i8'), ('weight', '<f8')])
```

---

To change the type of data within the structured array instead look at the answer of [@PaulPanzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58279038/9302488)